# RxJs pipe that holds data when loading, emits on load, allows emit when loaded

Tags: observable, rxjs6

I have two pipes, one is used as data for a graph, the other is used as a data loading indicator

```
graphData$: Observable<GraphData>;
dataLoaded$: Observable<boolean>;
```

I need the following pipe: `graphData$` emissions need to be stopped when `dataLoaded$` is emitting `false`. When `dataLoaded$` switches from `false` to `true`, I want the last stopped emission of `graphData$` to be emitted through the pipe. When `graphData$` is emitting `true` I want to simply bypass the pipe.

For now I'm solving it in the following fashion:

```
combineLatest([
  graphData$,
  dataLoaded$
]).pipe(
    filter(([_, dataLoaded]) => dataLoaded),
    map(([graphData]) => graphData)
).subscribe(graphData => blabla)
```

But there are an arbitrary number of data streams that need to be curbed by whether or not data is loaded, so I'd prefer a pipe that allows me to simply:

```
graphData$.pipe(
  dataLoaded()
).subscribe(graphData => blabla)
```

Any elegant solutions on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found one solution that might solve this:

```
dataLoaded = (): UnaryFunction<Observable<T>, Observable<T>> => 
  pipe(
    switchMap(val => 
      dataLoaded$.pipe(
        filter(Boolean),
        mapTo(val)
      )
    )
  )
```

Though I'd greatly appreciate feedback for why this might not be what I want (seems to be working correctly as far as I can see though)